# Eclipse: C project folder structure

Tags: c, eclipse, arm, directory

I have an existing C project with the following folder structure:

- bin
- proj
- src
- inc
- doc
- conf

When i launch Eclipse and create a new project the root project folder is polluted with:

- **.cproject**
- **.project**

Also the parent folder with:

- **.metadata**
- **RemoteSystemsTempFiles/**

**A want to continue use Eclipse as an C IDE with a my custom makefile (or not) but I want all Eclipse related files and folders to be put inside the proj directory. I need Eclipse to debug ARM targets.**

Is it possible? If not what is the next best thing?

I made a promise to myself to start a smooth transition from IDEs to vim with a custom makefile. I still need Eclipse to help me for debugging.
One step at a time...

Comment: The files `.project` and `.cproject` (and the `.settings` folder if it exists) contains the Eclipse-specific (general and C/C++) project configuration. The `.metadata` folder is some kind of a cache/temp folder, e. g. to store error/warnings markers, local file history and also workspace preferences. Files in a project are tracked and can cause changes in the `.metadata` folder. If the `.metadata` folder would be located in a project, this would result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Could I copy somehow the vital files folders in proj directory and add a rule in my custom makefile to remove the rest files that are temporary?
I would also tell git to ignore these files( .metadata etc ).

Comment: You can do it the other way around: the Eclipse Workspace folder as part of your project folder and linking instead of copying of all files and folder that you want to see in Eclipse or that are required by Eclipse.

Comment: If I understand correctly. I am supposed to make my proj folder the workspace of Eclipse and create virtual folders for my source code? I will try that right now. If that works that would be a brilliant answer.

Comment: @user3629249 The problem is not in my code. The code compiles and runs fine on target microcontroller. Please read again the description. I asked about Eclipse IDE configuration know-how.

Comment: @howlger solved my problem with his comment-answer. If you copy-paste or rewrite as a answer below I would be happy to mark it as the solution and give you all the credit. Eclipse is now working as I wanted...

Comment: Solution in github: https://github.com/TediCreations/C-with-make

Comment: @Tedi See my answer below. I recommend to remove [`C-with-make/proj/eclipse_workspace/.metadata`](https://github.com/TediCreations/C-with-make/tree/master/proj/eclipse_workspace/.metadata) and [`C-with-make/proj/eclipse_workspace/RemoteSystemsTempFiles`](https://github.com/TediCreations/C-with-make/tree/master/proj/eclipse_workspace/RemoteSystemsTempFiles) from Git. Change [`/home/tedi/Desktop/c-with-make/Makefile`](https://github.com/TediCreations/C-with-make/blob/master/proj/eclipse_workspace/myProject/.project#L30)&`/home/tedi/Desktop/c-with-make/src` to `PARENT-3-PROJECT_LOC/Makefile` etc.

Comment: @howlger Ok thanks again. Will fix these in the next few commits... I subscribed to your channel. ;-)

Comment: For my version of Eclipse I used  --> ${ProjDirPath}/../../../ instead of PARENT-3-PROJECT_LOC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files **`.project`** and **`.cproject`** (and the **`.settings`** folder if it exists) contains the Eclipse-specific (general and C/C++) **project configuration**.

The **`.metadata`** folder is a kind of **cache/temp folder** (to store error/warnings markers, local file history, etc.) and also used to store your **workspace preferences** (most of *Window > Preferences*).

Files in a project are tracked and can cause changes in the `.metadata` folder. If the `.metadata` folder would be located in a project, this could end in an infinite loop.

You could **use the workspace folder** of Eclipse (which contains the `.metadata` folder) **as part of your overall project folder** and **link** instead of copy all **files and folder that you want to see in Eclipse** or that are required by Eclipse **into your Eclipse project** (you can also mark some files and folders as [derived](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_derived.htm) to stop them from being tracked and to make them less visible in Eclipse).

Note, **do not share or move the `.metadata` folder** (and derived resources). In contrast, `.project`, `.cproject` and `.settings` are intended to be shared.